# What does notype() and notype mean when seeing the C++ library information using dumpbin?

Tags: c++, dumpbin

I used dumpbin /SYMBOLS to see the library I created. Some lines have notype() and notype in the output. What does that mean?

I guess notype() is function and notype is variable.
My thinking correct?

Comment: Still searching for the same thing in 2016. How time flies, but cryptic output stays cryptic.